# How can I make the viewport run faster?

Tags: modeling

I am working on a really complex mesh that I am using for product design, so I do not intend to render it. Due to its complexity, blender is running really slowly and it takes a few minutes to make any changes. Again I do not want to render this, I want to speed up blender in edit/object mode when I model the mesh.

Comment: Can you share some details? There are literally thousands of ways to optimize. Maybe some screenshots of thee modifiers and wireframes?

Right off the top of my head, reducing sub-divisioin modifiers and marking things as "smooth shading" can go a VERY long way on photo-realistic models with lots of polys

Answer (score 1):

Scene > Simplify
(don't go in edit mode with a mesh with a lot of subdivision: for example don't go in edit mode on a mesh you sculped)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also reduce Light Bouncing to a low degree. (There is no difference in the render result,if you're using values above 4 in my opinion)

[image]